# Aggregating Django object using Avg in an API view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, aggregate

I keep getting null values when applying `.aggregate(Avg(column_name))` in a Django API

My code looks like this:

Models.py

```
class Glucose_level(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patients, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    glucose_reading = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class GlucoseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Glucose_level
        fields = ('date', 'glucose_reading', 'id', 'patient_id', 'timestamp')
```

My API in views.py

```
class FourteenDayAvg(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = GlucoseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        patient_id = self.request.query_params.get('patient_id')
        sdate = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=14)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        edate = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        patient_list = Glucose_level.objects.filter(date__range =(sdate,date), 
        patient_id=patient_id).aggregate(Avg('glucose_reading'))
        return patient_list
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "glucose_reading": null
    }
]
```

Please let me know if something is wrong with my syntax.

Comment: Probably one of glucose_reading values in null, so the Avg call returns null also

Comment: none of the glucose readings appear null in the database